# How show loading window in async query?(or may be sync)

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

i have:

```
  function load_data(data) {

    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
    myMask.show();


    $.ajax({
            url: '/dostup/data_json.php',
            method: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data: {
                   epsg: data
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
              console.log('ошибка получения данных: '+data);
            },
            success: function(data2) {
                window[data] = data2;
                window[data+"_layer"].clearLayers();
                window[data+"_layer"].addData(eval(data));
                myMask.hide();
            }
    });

  }
```

And myMask hidden before window[data] loading on site(client).
I try set async: false and myMask not show(i try and beforeSend too).

P.S. i have:

```
 function search_handler(val) {
        search_list=[];
        for (var t = 0; t < layer_array.length; t++) {   //>
           if (window[layer_array[t]] != undefined && !eval(layer_array[t]).features) load_data(layer_array[t]);
           if (window[layer_array[t]] != undefined && eval(layer_array[t]).features) {
             for (var i = 0; i < eval(layer_array[t]).features.length; i++) {   //>
                search_list.push(eval(layer_array[t]).features[i]);
             }
           }
        }
  ....more script
 }
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) like that:

```
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    myMask.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    myMask.hide();
  });
```

Comment: better, but function search_handler() return empty array search_list, if second call search_handler() then fine.

Comment: @user15445 what you mean with 'not working' how exactly it is not working? I have made an example where it is working http://jsfiddle.net/b0wzk1j1/ as you see 'start' and 'success' appears in console regardless to async value. So it must be something wrong with your Ext.LoadMask.

Comment: i think very fast hide(), becouse for async:false ajaxStart/Stop execute for each $.ajax and for async:true for all $.ajax, i have array $.ajax for execute.

Comment: @user15445 hard to say what exactly. If you could make jsfiddle with exact issue (you might also consider creating/updating question to make a better relation to Ext.LoadMask as issue seems there) than I could try point you to what exactly is incorrect. So far you can try wrapping **hide** into **setTimeout** - to delay hide if you think that is an issue.

Comment: console.log() is working fine, but Ext.LoadMask() not working, but if leave myMask.show() and delete myMask.hide() then myMask show after ajax request, so i dunno...